# How can I read in https-based data using wget?

Tags: python, windows, wget

I am trying to train a linear regression model in jupyter notebook with Anaconda 3(conda 4.8.4) in my windows 10 system. While I was trying to read in the training data (csv file from a "https" website) with the program `wget`, I got an error

```
'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I had actually installed this program in both Anaconda prompt and jupyter notebook terminal, however I still get this error. Has anyone an idea how can I fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
! wget https://github.com/dataprofessor/data/raw/master/BostonHousing.csv
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rCfB.png)

Comment: What does it show, when you use "!wget --version" ?

Comment: How are you calling `wget` from your code? Why don't you use a python library such as `requests` or the `wget` python module? If you share the code you tried it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: @Kim Tang, it shows "  'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." after running "!wget --version".

Comment: That would mean then, that you don't have wget installed yet. Try "!pip install wget" to install it with pip.

Comment: @Kim Tang, I installed anaconda instead of python, so I thinks your suggestion "!pip install wget" does not work... I run "!pip install wget" at anaconda command prompt it can not recognize this command so shows "(base) C:\Users\qicao>!pip install wget
'!pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  Anyway I succeeded to get http data with the tool proposed by medic17...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a python tool instead of an external tool. It is easier to work with and you can ingest data in a way python and it's libraries expect.

Something as simple as this should work:

```
import requests

# Get data using a GET request
r = requests.get('https://github.com/dataprofessor/data/raw/master/BostonHousing.csv')

# Continue proccesing and prepare for neural network.

# Here I print the data recvied to stdout as an example. You can just as easly write to a file or anything else you like

print(r.content)
```

Alternatively since you already installed `wget` module you can call it like this `python -m wget "https://github.com/dataprofessor/data/raw/master/BostonHousing.csv"`